# Double the font-size in string with HTML/CSS content

Tags: php, html, css, string, variables

I've got a string like this:

```
$foo = 'height:200px;color:#CCC;font-size:12px';
```

Can I somehow double the font-size amount in the string?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: do you want to do it with regexp?

Comment: Why are you doing this, what do you want to achieve?, that will help in helping you out

Comment: I use a rich textfield in MySQL. But when I want to print it out, I want the font-size to be double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$foo  = 'height:200px;color:#CCC;font-size:12px';
$key  = 'font-size:';
preg_match('/' . $key . '(\d+)/', $foo, $matches);
$size = (int) $matches[1];
$foo  = str_replace($key . $size, $key . ($size * 2), $foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please used this code :

```
<?php

$foo = 'height:200px;color:#CCC;font-size:12px';
$styleArr   = explode(";",$foo);
$newStyleArr    = array();
foreach ($styleArr as $style) {
    $explode_str    = explode(":",$style);
    if($explode_str[0]=="font-size" && count($explode_str)>0) {
        $explode_str[1] = str_replace("px","",$explode_str[1]);
        $explode_str[1]     = ($explode_str[1]*2)."px;";
    }

    $newStyleArr[]  = implode(":",$explode_str);
}

echo implode(";",$newStyleArr);
?>
```

OUTPUT :

```
height:200px;color:#CCC;font-size:24px;
```